# Packaging a class directory into a Jar file

Tags: java, jar

I have a directory containing a sub-directory named `classes`. The `classes` sub-directory contains other directories and compiled `.class` files. I would like to assemble a Jar file from the content of the `classes` sub-directory.

How do I package a directory into a Jar file?

Comment: Using jar program/command shipping with JDK.

Comment: Well you can pack it to a ZIP-Archive and change the filetype to `.jar` or use the jar-tool like described by oracle http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/basicsindex.html

Comment: use the jar command.

Comment: Lol the questions you ask bud - its not all about reputation you know :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this:

```
jar cf myjarfile.jar Class1.class Class2.class
or
jar cf myjarfile.jar .\Path\To\My\Classes\Directory
```

Answer found in oracle's documentation [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/build.html).